# multiple case statement in VBA script

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am running into an error when writing these multiple 'case when' statements in Excel VBA. The scripting runs perfectly in SQL Server, but I am having trouble formatting it correctly in Excel VBA so that it can run correctly. Please help?!

Comment: How exactly did you try this in VBA? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Instead, try creating a Tally table and joining on it. Who would really write a case statement like that.

Comment: And BTW, if all you are bothered is how to write that in VBA, then try writing it as multiple strings no longer than 255 characters and concatenate. ie: dim sql as string = "select" & _ "  case when ..." & _ " when ...".

Comment: @CetinBasoz can you elaborate a little more? I attempted to concatenate, but I think may have done it incorrectly.

Comment: @CetinBasoz could you start it off for me? I keep getting error messages. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @jb_swole2013, I already did. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would write a long string in VBA:

```
    StrQuery = "Select" & _
" case when srvprovid like '01%' then 'AL'" & _
"      WHEN srvprovid like '02%' then 'AK'" & _
"      WHEN srvprovid like '03%' then 'AR'" & _
" ..."
```

And this is what I suggest you to do instead (just a sample showing the idea, didn't write full code):

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (srvProvId VARCHAR(10), id INT IDENTITY);
INSERT INTO @sample (srvProvId) VALUES 
('010'),
('01'),
('020'),
('030'),
('040');

DECLARE @states VARCHAR(1000) = 'AL,AK,AR,AZ,CA,CO,CT'; -- DE,DC,FL...
DECLARE @tally TABLE (id INT IDENTITY, abrv CHAR(2));

INSERT @tally (abrv)  
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@states, ',') ;

SELECT * 
FROM @sample t1
LEFT JOIN @tally t2 ON t1.srvProvId LIKE RIGHT('0'+CAST(t2.id AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+'%';
```